# can't make my RPI booting

Tags: sd-card, power

i m a manupilating RPI B+ for the first time excuse me for my language i m Tunisian and i m having problem with making my RPI  works headless ,the first one is i m using win32diskimager to write WHeezy on my SDcard,i m actually following a tutorial to make my RPI works on my laptop using local area connection but when i enter The SD card to extract file that i already written i can't open it,the second problem is i have this chargeur of my phone that in first time then it was corrupted (my chargeur 4.8v supply and 0.4A) remebering i m not connecting anything else with my RPI,now i have connected a usb alimentation to my laptop it first worked then turned off ,is there a chance that my RPI is corrupted while getting low alimentation!!i hope not , asking for help.thnks any way.

Comment: It might run off the laptop but don't use that charger.

Comment: @goldilocks i did command a new chargeur with 5v nd 1A ,i guess it ll work but still have my SDcard problem

Answer (score 1):

B+ should have 5v at least 1.2a (maybe higher current for USB devices - suggested even 2A+) - this information available on official FAQ : http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs